# How to make button tags visible in mobile view

Tags: html, css, customization, blogger

In my blog, I had customized  button tag in two different way their code are as follow:

```
    .button1 {
border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
box-sizing: inherit; 
background-color: #ffffff; 
margin-right: 1.7px; 
color: black; 
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 980;
padding: 6px 32px;
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
width: 96.6px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 22px; 
font-size: 16px;
font-family: domine;
display: inline-table;
}
.button2 { 
border: 2px solid rgb(255, 87, 51);
background-color: #FF5733;
box-sizing: inherit;
margin-right: 1.7px; 
color: white; 
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 980;
padding: 6px 42px;
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
width: 96.6px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 22px; 
font-size: 16px;
font-family: domine;
display: inline-table;}
.button2:hover {
  background-color: #FF5733;
  color: #000000;}
```

but there is a problem I customization which I have done is not visible in mobile view, It is shown as a default customization. How should I implement these customizations to mobile view?
Help me.

**By the way, I use these code:**

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 390px) {
.button2 { padding: 6px 32px;width: 84.6px;font-size: 16px;display: inline-table;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 390px) {
  .button1 { width: 76.6px;}
}}
```

**to make button tag customization visible in the mobile view. I had pasted these codes in CSS area of blogger blog, but no effect is seen in the mobile view please help me if I use wrong code or if I paste code in wrong place.**

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example with your view?

Comment: Now I try my best to explain my problem I hope now you can understand what I want to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is a simple thing but many people does it wrong: make sure to put the @media code below the other codes. 
Second, if you have the same **@media screen and (max-width: 390px)**, why don't you put both button style inside the same @media? like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 390px) {
   .button2 { padding: 6px 32px;width: 84.6px;font-size: 16px;display: inline-table;
    }
   .button1 { width: 76.6px;}
}
```

Oh, and this css should be put using the edit html option of your template.

Comment: But the error continue still the customization not appear in bobile view. Please see this page(https://shouttolearn.blogspot.com/p/downloads-ebook.html) in both desktop and mobile view and see the button i used their. Why in mobile view button not appear as desktop view. Code I have used same as I had written in my question and @media code I am using of what you had provide in your answer.

Comment: Ok, apparently you have a @ media only screen and (min-width: 980px) somewhere in your code overriding your style... try adding to your @ media a min-width like @ media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 390px) ... or try to find and change the overriding @ media or what is injecting that style into your page... can be a third party widget or something from the template you're using... can't help without more info... edit: had to separate the @ due to rules of stackoverflow but I hope you get the meaning.

Comment: Ok, digging a bit more into your code, you should look where you have this piece of code: /*-------Typography and ShortCodes-------*/ That was the only place where I could find a @ media that could be overriding your style AND it's located below the code present in your question. Hope it helps you finding a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir your suggestions work for me, I am very thankful to you. I have tried stackoverflow for first time and it's just made my day. Once again thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Such problem usually has one of these reasons:

1. Your server supports a cache. try to remove the cache from your browser.
2. make sure that `@media` code is below your main `.button2` and `.button1` codes.
3. make sure to put `@media` code in the same file as main button codes